# Undefined symbols for architecture .. in dynamic framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, compiler-errors, frameworks

I am working on an iOS framework which holds several third party frameworks and communicates with Unity using the UnitySendMessage C method.

I want to create a Dynamic Framework (supporting iOS8+) but i stumble upon the following compile error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
   "_UnitySendMessage", referenced from:
 ....
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

This method is called in my .m class and declared as shown below in my .h file:

```
void UnitySendMessage(const char* obj, const char* method, const char* msg);
```

When compiling as a static library it compiles and works fine but i get other crashes on the embedded 3rd party frameworks. As i can't control these frameworks i prefer to create a dynamic framework.

I've tried many compiler settings based on all other posts i could find but due to the embedded frameworks i need to support multiple architectures. None of the setting worked for me.

Also i tried to create another static framework and embed this into my 'parent' dynamic framework. I check this with lipo and the architecture seems to be added, but i still get the same undefined symbols error.

I am working on this for 2 days already so i really hope someone can point me in the right direction

**UPDATE**

Adding the flag "-undefined dynamic_lookup" solved the compile issue. However when adding the dynamic framework in a unity project it crashes when the method "UnitySendMessage" is triggered.

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
```

*When creating a static framework the method doesn't crash and works fine. Still don't understand what's the difference in this case with a dynamic framework.

The method is declared in my .h file as followed:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
    void UnitySendMessage(const char* obj, const char* method, const char* msg);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have a similar problem here. Static works, dynamic throws a linker error...

Comment: @martijn I know this was asked ~2 years ago but did you solve this issue?

Comment: did you solve this issue, I am facing this from past 3 days, not able to solve.

Comment: I have almost the same problem. I've build static library with UnitySendMessage method inside and it is fine. And after this i want to create podspec for this library and when podspec is validating using pos spec lint it try to link it and naturally fails with "Undefined symbols for architecture" because there is no implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the framework target in **Build settings Build active architecture only = NO**

if you are using **cocoapod** for managing your dependencies 
check pod target and put the **Build active architecture only = NO**

Comment: try also to delete your .m and .h and then copie it again : make sure to select  “Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)”
check the .h in build header and .m in compile source

Double click on the Header Search Paths item, and a popover will appear. Click the + button, and enter the following: $SOURCE_ROOT/include

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer! Unfortunately all suggestions didn't worked. Any other ideas what it could be?