# _UnitySendMessage missing symbols iOS dynamic framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I am getting the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_UnitySendMessage", referenced from:
```

When trying to call UnitySendMessage from a dynamic framework I am building.

This stack overflow question was unanswered and abandoned 2 years ago:

[Undefined symbols for architecture .. in dynamic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634748/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-in-dynamic-framework)

Comment: `UnitySendMessage` is a C function.. Perhaps you're calling it from C++?? Maybe you didn't link to libiPhone-lib.a?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't want to have to link to libiPhone in my framework as I want that to be provided in the end unity iPhone project. Or will it not be included in my framework?

Comment: try `extern "C" void UnitySendMessage(const char*, const char*, const char*) __attribute__ ((weak));` in the file where you are getting the error..  OR try adding `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup` your linker flags.. it's dangerous to ignore ALL undefined symbols of course.. so perhaps you can ignore just with `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` or something.. Not too sure.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

**1**.Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Scripting Backend*. Change that to *IL2CPP*.

If it is already set to IL2CPP, swtich it to Mono then back to IL2CPP.

Build and test. If that doesn't work, move in to #2.

**2**.Go to *Edit* --> *Project Settings* --> *Player* --> *Other Settings* --> *Architecture*. Change that to ARM64 instead of Universal or ARMv7.

Comment: Thanks for your help

I can't do #1 as I am in a framework that I am building, not the unity ios project.

I will try #2 but I'm assuming it will just do the same thing

Comment: Any one found answer to this question, same thing happening to me and I am not able to solve this.